# Android listview not refreshing properly

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview which will update fine only when a button is pressed. When the button is pressed, the listener calls a method which applies a new arrayadapter and the changes are shown.

However if I call the method without the invoke of a button, nothing happens until the fragment's lifecycle refreshes.

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Are you calling it within the UI thread?

Comment: I have tried the notifyDataSetChanged() method but nothing changes. Also the method is being called within a context menu switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be applying a new array adapter every time the data changes. What you should be doing is making mods to the array the adapter is pointing to, with out changing where the adapter is pointing, and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. see some other posts about this

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2708053/1116836
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250849/1116836
>
> http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html

that last one could be very helpful as a guide/tutorial on how it should be done.

Learning the best way to do this might take a bit of time, but once you figure it out it is a very easy and quick process doing it in other projects/areas from there on out.

Comment: Do you know why the method would work on a button invoke, but not on a context menu selection? I understand this is not the best way to approach the refresh, but why it is not working outside of a button invoke is baffling me.